# SVG - Greensock Timeline for animation

Tags: javascript, svg, gsap

What is the **GSAP** counterpart of the `additive` and `accumulate` animation attributes in **SVG**? I am animating using click events so I want to continue animation from the last state of the object. Or is there a way to access those attributes.

I am just starting out, so any links to guides or tutorials is appreciated.

```js
var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

function anim(evt) {
  if (window.svgDocument == null)
    svgDoc = evt.target.ownerDocument;

  rot('shape', 120);
}

function rot(target_id, angle) {
  var my_element = svgDoc.getElementById(target_id);
  var a = svgDoc.createElementNS(svgNS, "animateTransform");

  var bb = my_element.getBBox();
  var cx = bb.x + bb.width / 2;
  var cy = bb.y + bb.height / 2;

  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeName", "transform");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "attributeType", "XML");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "type", "rotate");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "dur", "1s");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "repeatCount", "1");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "freeze");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "additive", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "accumulate", "sum");
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "from", "0 " + cx + " " + cy);
  a.setAttributeNS(null, "to", angle + " " + cx + " " + cy);

  my_element.appendChild(a);
  a.beginElement();
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="500px" height="500px" viewBox="0 0 500 500" enable-background="new 0 0 500 500" xml:space="preserve">
  <g id="shape">
    <circle fill="#FFA557" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="254.186" cy="247.288" r="107.203" />
    <polygon fill="#8CFFD5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="239.634,218.5 225.083,193.5 239.634,168.5 
  268.736,168.5 283.288,193.5 268.736,218.5  " />
    <polygon fill="#8CFFD5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="239.634,268.5 225.083,243.5 239.634,218.5 
  268.736,218.5 283.288,243.5 268.736,268.5  " />
    <polygon fill="#8CFFD5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="195.634,243.5 181.083,218.5 195.634,193.5 
  224.737,193.5 239.288,218.5 224.737,243.5  " />
    <polygon fill="#8CFFD5" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="282.635,243.5 268.083,218.5 282.635,193.5 
  311.736,193.5 326.288,218.5 311.736,243.5  " />
  </g>
  <g onclick="anim(evt)">
    <rect x="123.5" y="391.5" fill="#6E005D" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="268" height="77" />
    <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 184.0811 439.5081)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'ComicSansMS'" font-size="36">Click Me</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/twg3mzmh/) the kind of effect you are trying to reproduce using `TweenMax`? Let me know.

***Update #1:***

Using `TimelineMax`:

- Keep adding new `TweenMax` tweens into an existing `timeline`
  instance by using the [`add()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/add/) method of `TimelineMax`.
- Check to see if `timeline` is currently in a playing state, if not, `play()` it.

***[jsFiddle #1](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/twg3mzmh/1/)***.

***Update #2:***

- Increment the speed of `timeline` using
  [`timeScale()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/timeScale/) on a per-click basis.
- Set a cap on this `timeScale()` property.
- Add an `onComplete` callback to the `timeline` instance to [`clear()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/clear/) the `timeline`.

***[jsFiddle #2](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/twg3mzmh/3/)***.

Comment: Let it put it this way. When i click a button, it should add animation to the time line (i am using timelinemax btw). So clicking the button 3 times should theoretically stack 3 animations on the timeline queue and so when i click the button the second time when the 1st animation is already in progress, it should not interfere with the ongoing animation, and just wait till it finishes. After the first one completes, the next one can start.

Comment: So even the duration is being added continously right?  So the second click of a button means to add another 1 second animation to the on going animation?

Comment: Yes, hats right, lets say i clicked once. So an anim of 1s will start. If 0.5 sec later if i click again, another anim of 1s will be queued to start after the 0.5 s. Atm, clicking continuously speeds up the previous anim and the total duration drops. I don't want the animations to interfere, just stay in a queue and exeute one by one.

Comment: Got it. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: @AnuragDaolagajao: Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/twg3mzmh/2/) produce your desired result?

Comment: Yes, perfert, exactly what i was looking for. Just one more thing, Can it be modified so that just like the initial case, the animation speeds up but i can control the speed of the anim?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83524/discussion-between-tahir-ahmed-and-anurag-daolagajao).